# Jupyter notebooks in chrome application mode

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I can start Jupyter notebook (6.0.2) in Chrome application mode just fine using the line `c.NotebookApp.browser = '"C:\Path\chrome.exe" --app=%s'` in the config file.

The problem is that every script I run opens in a "normal" Chrome window. Any suggestions?

EDIT

It works with JupyterLab (1.2.3)

Comment: Which config file?

Comment: The one generated with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`